# blend edges navabar not blending with background

Tags: css, navbar, blend

I am trying to get the edges of the button to blend with the header with rounded edges, I have tried to border-radius of 25px, but it shows the corners as a darker color.

```
button {
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0,136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

button:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169,0.8);
}
```

```
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="Logo"> 
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav_links">
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>  
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a class="cta" href="#"><button>Contact</button></a>
</header>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMkKD.png)

Comment: Can you show us your code

Comment: button {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0,136, 169, 1);
    border: none;
    
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

button:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169,0.8);
}

Comment: can you please share the entire code of your header i see there is not issue in button. there is something else causing issue.